# SQL simulator on Prolog

Tags: sql, prolog, simulator

i need to do a SQL simulator on Prolog. i need to simulate some functions like create_table, insert, delete, update_table, select_table, drop_table, show_table, etc. I am learning how to do asserts and retracts but im getting some errors in my first function create_table(N,A) where N is the name of the table and A a list with the atributtes

An example is create_table("student",["name","lastname","age"]). This will create my table named "student" with the atributes ["name","lastname","age"].

I was searching how to work with assert and i see i need to do dynamic before making assert, then my code is.

```
len([],0). 
len([_|T],N)  :-  len(T,X),  N  is  X+1.

create_table(_, []):-!.
create_table(N, Atributos):- len(Atributos, L), dynamic N/L, assert(N(Atributos)).
```

But i get this error **:7: Syntax error: Operator expected** on this line

```
create_table(N, Atributos):- len(Atributos, L), dynamic N/L, assert(N(Atributos)).
```

What im doing wrong? excuse me, i dont speak good english.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, seems you're using SWI-Prolog....
Your code could be (note that len/2 can be replaced by the builtin length/2)

```
create_table(N, Atributos):-
 length(Atributos, L),
 dynamic(N/L),
 T =.. [N|Atributos], % this missing 'constructor' was the cause of the error message
 assert(T). % this is problematic
```

There is an important 'design' problem: the CREATE TABLE SQL statement works at metadata level.

If you do, for instance,

```
?- assertz(student('Juan', 'Figueira', 20)).
```

pretending that the *predicate* student/3 holds table data, you're overlapping data and metadata

Comment: I got a solution, but now when i make querys i get names on ascii code, do u know why?

      **?- create_table("hombres",["nombre","edad"]).
      true.
      ?- tabla("hombres",X).
      X = [[110, 111, 109, 98, 114, 101], [101, 100, 97, 100]].**

Comment: check Prolog syntax for *atoms*: use *single* quotes instead of double quotes, like in my example

Answer (score 0):

using dynamic/1 and assert is a tricky non-logical aspect of Prolog, and dynamically creating dynamic predicates is really unusual. Fundamentally you cannot have a Prolog query with the predicate name as a variable e.g.

```
query(N,X) :- N=student, N(X).
```

My suggestion is you remove a layer of complexity and have *one* dynamic predicate 'table', and assert your SQL tables as new 'table' clauses i.e.

```
:- dynamic table/2.

:- assertz(table(student,['Joe','Young',18])).

query(N,X) :- table(N,X).

:- query(student,[Name,Lastname,Age]).
```

Comment: yes, it's tricky but doable. I did it to manage an [e-commerce](http://www.erboristeriasantanna.it) (mySQL DB) feed & dump.

Comment: There's `call(Predicate, Arg1, Arg2, ...)`. Or, as @CapelliC has in his answer, the `=..` operator for building a functor from a list. So dynamic predicate names are easy to manage in Prolog.

Comment: @lurker: the difficult part - that I didn't managed to solve satisfactorily - was to 'modularize' the public interface.